# svn repostory save the code changes, can I sync the code not only changes

Tags: svn, subversion-edge

On my server, the svn rep likes this:(save changes)

```
conf
db
format
hooks
locks
README.txt
```

But in local rep is:(code in here)

```
README.md
index.html
```

I want save the code on server not only the code-changes. Because it's a website.

(I don't know whether to express clearly)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'll starting from reading SVN Book instead of wasting our time?

SVN repository is **database**, not mirror of your local tree. When you commit, it stores *some data* inside `db` directory in repository (but you haven't to be interested in technical details) and this data **stores** you **code and historical changes** in repository.

Just commit and try

Comment: *Sorry about waste your time* but I just try to read <SVN Book> and the `hooks` is at the fifth chapter. I have not read that chapter. Now I have solved the problem. sorry.